# Трансляция веб камеры в QVideoWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, видео, cv2, videocapture

Как вместо открытия нового окна транслировать в `QVideoWidget`

[image: Интерфейс]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Данный код открывает новое окно.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует куда вы хотите вставить трансляцию с веб камеры.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import cv2
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Camera:
    def __init__(self, camera):
        self.camera = camera
        self.cap = None

    def openCamera(self):
        self.vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.vc.set(3, 640)                      
        self.vc.set(4, 480)                      

        if not self.vc.isOpened():
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setText("Не удалось открыть камеру.")
            msgBox.exec_()
            return


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, camera = None):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.camera = camera

        self.label = QLabel()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.nextFrameSlot)

        self.start()
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.show)

    def start(self):
        self.camera.openCamera()
        self.timer.start(1000. / 24)

    def nextFrameSlot(self):
        rval, frame = self.camera.vc.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    camera = Camera(0)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window(camera)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: теперь она открывает поверх главного окна еще одно окно с трансляцией

Comment: @Stas я не понимаю вас, о каком главном окне вы говорите?

Comment: В окне (см. Скрин) прямоугольник и в него нужно выводить трансляцию.

Comment: @Stas я не знаю что за скрин вы опубликовали, но если у вас есть проблема вставить виджет в какое-то свое приложение - опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiWpvJjL5oj-iCjTvteCkLrMakl3?e=h9ZPLc

Comment: @Stas я вас понял и написал вам уже два раза что надо сделать. Напишу еще раз  (последний раз)  - предоставьте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует куда вы хотите вставить трансляцию с веб камеры.

Comment: Действительно, не очень понятно то, что Вы хотите, судя по переписке с  S. Nick. Какую роль должно выполнять прямоугольное окно, а какую квадратная рамка? Или это не рамка, а еще один виджет? Объясните получше, попробую помочь

Answer (score 0):

Если по какой-либо причине нужно использовать цикл while, то посмотрите мой код. Я не специалист, написал как сумел, но код работает.

***main***

```
import sys
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class New(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()
        loadUi("form_cam.ui", self)
        self.SHOW.clicked.connect(self.camera)

    def displayImage(self, img, window):   # Эта функция необходима для отрисовки в виджете Label
        qformat = QImage.Format_Indexed8
        if len(img.shape) == 3:
            if (img.shape[2]) == 4:
                qformat = QImage.Format_RGBA8888
            else:
                qformat = QImage.Format_RGB888
        img = QImage(img, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], qformat)
        img = img.rgbSwapped()
        self.imgLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        self.imgLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img))

    def camera(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            self.displayImage(frame, 1)  # Это вместо привычного cv2.imshow()
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            # cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        super().closeEvent(e)
        sys.exit() # добавил для остановки процессов в IDE

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***form_cam.ui***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>663</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <property name="sizeGripEnabled">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="modal">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_3">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>11</x>
     <y>11</y>
     <width>778</width>
     <height>641</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(200, 191, 200);</string>
   </property>
   <property name="title">
    <string>GroupBox</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="imgLabel">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>640</width>
      <height>480</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Maximum">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="minimumSize">
     <size>
      <width>640</width>
      <height>480</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="maximumSize">
     <size>
      <width>640</width>
      <height>480</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="lineWidth">
     <number>7</number>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
    <property name="wordWrap">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>291</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Трансляция с вэб камеры:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="SHOW">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>350</x>
      <y>600</y>
      <width>93</width>
      <height>28</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>пуск</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: Результат]